# Assembly.isDynamic does not contain a definition

Tags: c#

when im trying to use isDynamic i've got a message 'Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'isDynamic' and no accesible extension method 'isDynamic' accepting a first argument of type 'Assembly' could be found.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.isdynamic?view=netframework-4.7.2
I change my project framework 3.5 to 4.0 but still nothing.. why?

Comment: Is that a typo? It should be `IsDynamic` instead of `isDynamic`.

Comment: maybe because of case? "**I**sDynamic"

Comment: nvm, really tired today :D sorry and thanks for help <3